# NAnt: How to Load External NAnt Scripts Inside A Custom Task

Tags: nant

In short, my problem is:

**How to load an NAnt script in side a custom task, and execute it?**

---

Detailed explanation:

In our current project build, we need to execute external programs. The external programs need to be located before the build kicks off. (coz it takes so looong time)

What I want is to have some NAnt module, like those FindXXX.cmake modules in CMake, so I can have modules like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="FindSQLServerCore" default="FindSQLServer">
  <target name="FindSQLServer">
    <module>
      <path>
        <pathelement dir="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn" />
        <pathelement dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn" />
      </path>
      <files>
        <file name="SQLCmd.exe" />
      </files>
    </module>
  </target>
</project>
```

And when I need to include SQLServer in my build script, I can do:

```
<find module="SQLServer" required="true" />
```

My way to do it is by create 2 custom tasks: **FindTask** & **ModuleTask**.

**FindTask** is going to locate the *FindXXX.include* and loaded it into current NAnt project.

**ModuleTask** is going to find specified file under given path and return results.

But I cannot find ways to create & execute NAnt tasks by loading a build script in **FindTask**. The *Project.CreateTask(XmlNode)* only accepts node that is already loaded but not from newly loaded XML.

Is there a way to create task by loading a build script inside a custom task?
*Or is my way doing this the NAnt style? Any better ways to achieve same goal?*

---

PS. You might ask why not just use

```
<include file="FindSQLServer.include" />
```

The reason I'm not doing it this way is I want to pass the *required* parameter in, but not set it as a variable and pass it in.

---

You can get the NANT extension here:[NAntFind@github](https://github.com/xinhuang/NAntFind)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to load an NAnt script and execute it inside a custom task is to create a new project, and load the script using the project, then execute. Example:

```
var findProject = new Project(nantModule, Level.Info, Project.IndentationLevel);
findProject.Execute();
```

If the project fails, an exception should be thrown out.